# Help on weight painting and rigging .dae import from Google Sketchup

Tags: rigging, import, weight-painting

I created a 3D model with Google SketchUp (with default SketchUp textures) and exported it into a .dae with the export options: Export Two-Sided Faces, Export Edges, Triangulate All Faces, Preserve Component Hierarchies, and Export Texture Maps checked.

Then imported it into Blender, and created an Armature for the bones, next parented the model to the Armature.  After all that I went into weight painting and couldn't get it to fully paint even with it on full strength.  My goal is to get the rigged model into Unity and do some animations in Blender. I need help with the weight painting, can someone walk me through this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?